# Can we wish a non jew, "Happy Holidays"

Tags: halacha, gentiles

According to the Jewish law are we allowed to wish a non-Jewish neighbor Happy Holidays?

Comment: For what it's worth, Rabbi Hershel Schachter has a shiur about office holiday parties where he suggests "season's greetings." I'm not sure about "happy holidays." Personally I have given end-of-year tips around December 15th with a note that says "Happy New Year." (Rav Moshe Feinstein okays celebrating New Year's.)